# Adding new line using sed on specific pattern

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I want to split "vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435 (hdf5)splitmehere" on the second space. How can I accomplish that using sed?

MY INPUT:

```
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435 (hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere(somedata)"
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435 (hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere"
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435 (hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere"
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435"
"product:" (hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere(somedata)"
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435"
"product:" (hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere"
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435"
"product:" (hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere"
```

I have tried is to use a variant of this expression:

```
sed -r 's/(*.*) (*.*) (*.*)/\1 \2 \3/'
```

Comment: That exact `sed` expression is invalid, and gives an error (using GNU sed).  If it were "fixed" by removing the erroneous `*`s, it would do nothing (giving the same output as input).  Could you show the "variant" that you actually tried?

Comment: I lost it from terminal history. However, I have another expression: sed -e "s/ /\n/2". Splits on the second space occurence. Later I will do what I want to do on the line that starts from (, and { tr '\n' ' ' < ${datarss}input.txt; echo; } | sed '$s/ $//'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
$ sed 's/\("vulnid":\) \(.*\) \(.*\)"/\1 \2"\n"product": "\3"/' file
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435"
"product": "(hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere(somedata)"
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435"
"product": "(hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere"
"vulnid": "CVE-2018-17435"
"product": "(hdf5)splitmehere"
"stuff":"stuffhere"
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I had something similar but with typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your own suggestion

```
sed -e "s/ /\n/2"
```

nearly does what you describe.  All that remains is to put the extra `"product:"` text around the linebreak:

```
sed -e 's/ /"\n"product:" /2'
```

(I changed the outer quotes to single-quotes, in order to use double-quotes inside the expression.)

Some versions of `sed` may not interpret `\n` as a newline.  The [`sed` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) states:

> A line can be split by substituting a <newline> into it. The application shall escape the <newline> in the replacement by preceding it by a <backslash>.

ie.

```
sed -e 's/ /"\
"product:" /2'
```